# Spring boot Camel ActiveMQ apache geronimo vulnerability

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, activemq-artemis, geronimo

I'm using Camel in Spring Boot to send messages to an ActiveMQ Artemis queue using `camel-jms-starter`, `artemis-jms-client` and `camel-jms`. The issue is that Jenkins has found vulnerability in nested dependency `org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jms_2.0_spec`.
If I exclude it, it will not work.
Is there a way to keep using Camel in Spring Boot to send message in ActiveMQ queue without Apache Geronimo JMS?
These are my Camel dependencies for ActiveMQ:

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-jms</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>artemis-jms-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-jms-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

I do not use any configuration bean because Spring Boot does it automatically via properties

```
spring.artemis.mode=native
spring.artemis.host=localhost
spring.artemis.port=61616
spring.artemis.user=admin
spring.artemis.password=admin
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the vulnerability that Jenkins found in `org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jms_2.0_spec`? What exactly did it report?

Comment: It reports: 
Found dependencies with invalid/not allowed version: - org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jms_2.0_spec:1.0-alpha-2  
Nothing more

Comment: That's not a "vulnerability" per se. Jenkins is just complaining that the version name doesn't conform to expectation.

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly exclude the Apache Geronimo dependency from `artemis-jms-client`, e.g.:

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>artemis-jms-client</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
               <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
               <artifactId>geronimo-jms_2.0_spec</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Then you can add a dependency on the Eclipse JMS API implementation, e.g.:

```xml
    <dependency>
       <groupId>jakarta.jms</groupId>
       <artifactId>jakarta.jms-api</artifactId>
       <version>2.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

That said, it is **very** strange that the Apache Geronimo JMS API would be flagged with a vulnerability since it is just an API. In other words, it's just Java `interface` and empty `class` definitions.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't know why it results vulnerable. I'm surprised too. 
Anyway excluding it and using jakarta-jms gives me this error:
 org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client 389 [ERROR] AMQ214013: Failed to decode packet
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AMQ219032: Invalid type: 1

Comment: I just performed a sanity check using the Jakarta dependency and everything worked fine. The provider of the JMS API really has *nothing* to do with the wire format used by the client implementation. My guess is that this error is being caused by something else. Can you elaborate on the test you're performing?